# How would i implement interaction between unmanaged bean and JSF component?

Tags: jsf, websocket

I have a Web Socket endpoint that can receive many connections; each Web Socket session carries properties like HttpSession ID. If i receive something on a Web Socket session, how can i invoke some UIComponent's `decode()` method or `setValue()` method? The WebSocket endpoint is initialized via `ServletContainerInitializer`.

What i tried was using JSF events but since the different scopes, it fails - i can't obtain a reference to FacesContext. CDI events didn't work as well.

Comment: Hi, [mcve] please of what you tried, CDI events are needed, FacesContext is not. JSF events are for inside pages or components and also not related

Comment: Why don't you simply use `<f:websocket>`?

Comment: @BalusC , i need to push from client to server over binary websocket and once this is done, set a value of a component. f:websocket goes from server to client and the javadoc for @ Push suggests usage of jsf.ajax.request(). I guess i can just do the bulk in websocket binary and when i'm done, push message to client to trigger a lightweight jsf.ajax.request() to the component. It's dirty, but should suffice until i figure out how to do it with CDI events.

Comment: @Kukeltje , unfortunately the thing is in wild shape at the moment and can't easily refactor to short and sweet example. Your point on CDI events is noted and I will attempt it in the future again. In the mean time, i will just go around it and cheat a little - see above message. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm I assumed you were using `f:websocket`, You are not? Then please remove the jsf-2.3 tag (but don't add the jsf-2.2 tag again since it is not a jsf-2.2 specfific question). Adding the version and implementation info in the question is a good thing to do though. And http://showcase.omnifaces.org/push/socket contains a good example of how to use `f:websocket` (`o:websocket` formed the basis for it)

Comment: *"i need to push from client to server"* Why don't you simply use `<f:ajax>`?

Comment: Comp i'm writing moves lots of tiny files together or big ones. Needs to be protocol-light and communicate back progress; be able to drop connection when custom/mutable conditions are met (like max size (set via EL)) and so on. All of which WebSocket fits the bill. Did it the lame way by sending an ID string back to client, which on submit the comp will use to find the files. Works nice, i guess, but can be improved; thus i'm investigating how to reach comp directly. Can send you github invite to private WIP repo if sounds interesting, but it's hard to gut it for a minimum example.